# Как проверить содержание исключения в списке исключений

Tags: python, исключения, python-3.9

Есть список исключений

```
ERR = [
    ValueError,
    NameError
]
```

И есть "вызыватель" исключений

```
try:
    raise ValueError("Вставить текст")
except Exception as e:
    pass
```

Мне нужно с помощью чего либо проверить содержится или исключение в списке

Как кто так

```
if e in ERR:
    print("Вставить текст")
else:
    print("Не вставить текст")
``
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я решил поэкспериментировать и понял то что можно написать

```
if e.__class__ in ERR:
```

То всё заработает

Код

```
ERR = [
    ValueError,
    NameError
]

try:
    raise ValueError("Вставить текст")
except Exception as e:
    if e.__class__ in ERR:
        print("Вставить текст")
    else:
        print("Не вставить текст")
```

> Вывод: Вставить текст

Comment: Как и `type(e) in ERR`

Comment: `if isinstance(e, ERR):`...